# Retransmitted packets - how bad is it, what's normal?

Tags: linux, netstat

Netstat always shows me retransmitted packets:

```
$ netstat -s -t

Tcp:
    30 segments retransmitted
```

That's on my linux server a few hours after a reboot. What are normal to be expected numbers here?

How could one easily find out the reasons for the retransmits without having to fire up wireshark or similar non standard tooling?

Comment: FYI, the usual terminology in English for this is "packets", not "packages".

Comment: Also, this question doesn't seem to be related to programming, so you probably want to ask at Unix.SE, ServerFault, or SuperUser.

Comment: But you might like to compare this to the number of packets successfully transmitted, which is probably in the millions or billions.  30 out of that number is a negligibly small fraction.

Comment: A certain number of retransmitted packets is normal. A few percentages is fine. See [Finding cause of TCP retransmission within a LAN](https://serverfault.com/q/143910/332034)